# Is there a website that stores printers hardware IDs?

Tags: printer, hardware-detection

I'm working with about 200 different models of printers, each printer model has unique hardware IDs. I know I can extract them by plugging the printer to the PC but it's time consuming and I don't have direct access to all of the hardware, are there any website that keep a list? Or is there any way to retrieve them from producers website?

I'm aware of https://treexy.com/products/driver-fusion/database/printers/ but they've only got some of the printers that I need

Comment: The Microsoft Catalogue is best for this in most cases. Install Printers using Windows Device Update or via Devices and Printers.

Comment: @John thanks, how do I query the Catalogue by printer model and extract the IDs?

Comment: I am not certain. Try going to the Microsoft catalog and look up the printer.  I normally just need the driver, not the hardware ID

Comment: @John nvm I already figured it out, thanks a lot, if you want just add it as an answer to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Catalog is best for this in most cases. Install Printers using Windows Device Update or via Devices and Printers.

You can access the Microsoft Catalog on line and look up the printer. You can most likely access the data you need there.